# Clock-related terms starting with "C" and "F"

Tags: single-word-requests, time

Are there any clock-related terms starting with "C" and "F"?

I have a pocket watch with these letters at the bottom, see the picture.

[image]

Here I found more examples:

- https://i.etsystatic.com/25146363/r/il/8be430/2715628756/il_1140xN.2715628756_5oim.jpg
- https://i.etsystatic.com/16309891/r/il/8c3f83/2394967974/il_1140xN.2394967974_hczz.jpg

Comment: I would think that's a maker's mark, perhaps Clemence Freres?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmm, a watch for £20? Or "China Forged"? :)

Comment: Maybe not them! But all your examples show exactly the same dial.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You might be right. I was just wandering, if there might be some weird rare words for morning/afternoon, day/night or something like that, like the pair deosil/widdershins for the rotations.

Comment: I found one a similar one, but with letters "T" and "D": https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0273/5915/0164/products/celestial_zodiac_pocket_watch_both_1024x1024@2x.jpg?v=1589196948

Comment: This guy says that T stands for tritium - http://www.watchesandbeyond.com/watches101.asp

Comment: And [the same watch but no tiny letters](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Quartz-Pocket-Watch-Mens-Stainless-Steel-White-Dial-Arabic-Numerals-Gift-Pendant/418245707). I’m pretty sure that the letters are meaningful at some point in the watch making process to people who may not speak English, but not to anyone else.

Comment: there is also a watchmaker called Frederique Constant, take a pic of the back of the watch so we can get more context on the maker

Comment: There is no appropriate expansion of CF listed at the [Free Dictionary acronyms/initialisms site](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CF). This increasingly looks like a search for watch-manufacturer-related labels rather than for a standard English usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even that is an asnwer! If a community of language aware people doesn't see any suitable solution, then *this* is the solution!

Answer (score -1):

I think CF is some sort of designation for the 24-hour hands on you watch. Possibly some sort of military time designation.
If I had more time I would research this further for you but hopefully, it gets you on the right track. Good luck with your quest, it's one of the most interesting ones this morning.

Comment: I'm having trouble leaving this one unanswered, no I'm wondering if CF is Latin for something, or depending on where the watch is made is there a 24 hour, or military time translation for CF, in the language of the watchmaker?

Comment: Hello, Kevin. Until such time as you can find and add supporting evidence, this shouldn't be posted as more than a comment.

Comment: I have no clue where the clock has been made, most probably in China or similar :)

Comment: @KevinBLeigh In which programming language or library or framework does the term **CF** stand for the **24-hour format**?

Comment: Agreed @EdwinAshworth, I removed the reference to programming.

Comment: I've not removed the comment. To quote Matt Gutting, 'Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case an encyclopedia, dictionary, or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer.' Answers lacking supporting references come over as (and often are) no more than opinion, and belong in 'comments' rather than 'answers'.